# installing sql server management studio 2017

Tags: sql-server, sql, sql-server-2012

i want to install ssms2017 but it get error code 0x800b0003

here is the log file

```
[3744:1E78][2019-10-27T16:43:04]e310: Failed to verify payload: HelpViewer2_3 at path: C:\ProgramData\Package Cache\.unverified\HelpViewer2_3, error: 0x800b0003. Deleting file.
[3744:1E78][2019-10-27T16:43:04]e000: Error 0x800b0003: Failed to cache payload: HelpViewer2_3
[2C8C:2648][2019-10-27T16:43:04]e314: Failed to cache payload: HelpViewer2_3 from working path: C:\Users\ASUS\AppData\Local\Temp\{f3eaa58d-dbb7-494a-ac5f-89d85140048c}\HelpViewer2_3, error: 0x800b0003.
[2C8C:2648][2019-10-27T16:43:04]e349: Application requested retry of payload: HelpViewer2_3, encountered error: 0x800b0003. Retrying...
[3744:1E78][2019-10-27T16:43:06]e000: Error 0x800b0003: Failed authenticode verification of payload: C:\ProgramData\Package Cache\.unverified\HelpViewer2_3
[3744:1E78][2019-10-27T16:43:06]e000: Error 0x800b0003: Failed to verify signature of payload: HelpViewer2_3
[3744:1E78][2019-10-27T16:43:06]e310: Failed to verify payload: HelpViewer2_3 at path: C:\ProgramData\Package Cache\.unverified\HelpViewer2_3, error: 0x800b0003. Deleting file.
[3744:1E78][2019-10-27T16:43:06]e000: Error 0x800b0003: Failed to cache payload: HelpViewer2_3
[2C8C:2648][2019-10-27T16:43:06]e314: Failed to cache payload: HelpViewer2_3 from working path: C:\Users\ASUS\AppData\Local\Temp\{f3eaa58d-dbb7-494a-ac5f-89d85140048c}\HelpViewer2_3, error: 0x800b0003.
[2C8C:25D0][2019-10-27T16:43:07]e000: Error 0x800b0003: Failed while caching, aborting execution.
[3744:0BF8][2019-10-27T16:43:07]i330: Removed bundle dependency provider: {f3eaa58d-dbb7-494a-ac5f-89d85140048c}
[3744:0BF8][2019-10-27T16:43:07]i352: Removing cached bundle: {f3eaa58d-dbb7-494a-ac5f-89d85140048c}, from path: C:\ProgramData\Package Cache\{f3eaa58d-dbb7-494a-ac5f-89d85140048c}\
[2C8C:25D0][2019-10-27T16:43:07]e000: MainViewModel.OnBundleAction: Bundle action failed: The form specified for the subject is not one supported or known by the specified trust provider (0x800B0003)
[2C8C:25D0][2019-10-27T16:43:07]i399: Apply complete, result: 0x800b0003, restart: None, ba requested restart:  No
[2C8C:37D8][2019-10-27T16:43:45]i000: MainViewModel.OpenUrl: Opening url: C:\Users\ASUS\AppData\Local\Temp\SsmsSetup\SSMS-Setup-ENU_20191027164227.log
```

Answer (score 0):

> i want to install ssms2017 but it get error code 0x800b0003

The executable is corrupt, 0x800b0003 is exclusively connected, to a corrupt executable.

The message within the error log, “Failed to verify payload”, confirms this fact your executable is corrupt.

You need to download the executable again to solve your problem.